# Test on device ok, on emulator NULLPOINTER

Tags: android, android-activity, android-fragments, android-emulator

My app show mapfragment and paint few markers on it.
When I run on real device, everithing is ok, but when I use AVD emulator or Genymotion emulator I've got this kind of error (from Logcat):

```
06-18 11:51:02.743: E/AndroidRuntime(1825): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-18 11:51:02.743: E/AndroidRuntime(1825): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {com.flex.sklepik/com.flex.sklepik.ReadComments}: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-18 11:51:02.743: E/AndroidRuntime(1825):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2120)
06-18 11:51:02.743: E/AndroidRuntime(1825):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2135)
06-18 11:51:02.743: E/AndroidRuntime(1825):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1668)
06-18 11:51:02.743: E/AndroidRuntime(1825):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
06-18 11:51:02.743: E/AndroidRuntime(1825):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
06-18 11:51:02.743: E/AndroidRuntime(1825):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-18 11:51:02.743: E/AndroidRuntime(1825):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
06-18 11:51:02.743: E/AndroidRuntime(1825):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
06-18 11:51:02.743: E/AndroidRuntime(1825):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-18 11:51:02.743: E/AndroidRuntime(1825):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
06-18 11:51:02.743: E/AndroidRuntime(1825):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
06-18 11:51:02.743: E/AndroidRuntime(1825):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
06-18 11:51:02.743: E/AndroidRuntime(1825):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-18 11:51:02.743: E/AndroidRuntime(1825): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-18 11:51:02.743: E/AndroidRuntime(1825):     at com.flex.sklepik.ReadComments.wczytajMape(ReadComments.java:423)
06-18 11:51:02.743: E/AndroidRuntime(1825):     at com.flex.sklepik.ReadComments$LoadComments.onPreExecute(ReadComments.java:299)
06-18 11:51:02.743: E/AndroidRuntime(1825):     at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:391)
06-18 11:51:02.743: E/AndroidRuntime(1825):     at com.flex.sklepik.ReadComments.onResume(ReadComments.java:160)
06-18 11:51:02.743: E/AndroidRuntime(1825):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1150)
06-18 11:51:02.743: E/AndroidRuntime(1825):     at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:3832)
06-18 11:51:02.743: E/AndroidRuntime(1825):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2110)
06-18 11:51:02.743: E/AndroidRuntime(1825):     ... 12 more
```

And 
Code from line 423 looks like this:

```
public boolean wczytajMape() {
        if (mMap == null) {
            SupportMapFragment mapFrag = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                    .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
            mMap = mapFrag.getMap();
            mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(this); \\----->423 line
            mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

        }
        return (mMap != null);

    }
```

This error is really annoying and it happens on API 10 and API 17, this I was checked. I didn't test it on another version. Anyone can help me?

Comment: Check on the google emulator. You are trying on normal emulator which does not have MAP.

Comment: That means your mMap is `NULL` at that position.

Comment: Yes I know but why on real device everything is ok??

Comment: Are you using android studio ?

Comment: Eclipse and genymotion

Answer (score 0):

Check your emulator (AVD Manager) has Google Play API version, if not you will not be able to use maps and more features

Hope it helps

EDIT: I am afraid I was wrong, you will not be able to use maps in your emulator directly. Google is not providing means to do it.

There are no official ways to have these features, but they are highly discouraged, so I will not recommend you using them.

Comment: Where can i check this?

Comment: what do you think about it http://hmkcode.com/run-google-map-v2-on-android-emulator/

Answer (score 0):

Managed to get it to work by using the OnInfoWindowClickListener instead.

Try this code too:

```
   Marker marker_1; 

   mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener((OnMarkerClickListener));

   @Override
   public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
   // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     if(marker.equals(marker_1)){
        Log.w("Click", "test");
        return true;
    }
    return false;           
   }
```

Before that please check your SDK manager for the google play map showing
For Eclipse:

Step to follow :

- Select Window > Android SDK Manager.

*Install the Google Play services SDK.

Scroll to the bottom of the package list, expand Extras, select Google Play services, and install it. If you're using Android Studio, also install Google Repository (it provides the Maven repository used for Gradle builds).

*Install a compatible version of the Google APIs platform.

- Install package

Refer this[ [[LINK]](http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html#Install)for more reference.

Comment: I've got Google Play services SDK right now, without it I couldn't compile my app and run on real device.